# Microsoft Bot: Show options from database instead of enums

Tags: botframework

In the example bot implementations from Microsoft, they use enums to define options for dialog, as shown in the example below:

```
public enum LengthOptions { SixInch, FootLong };

public enum BreadOptions { NineGrainWheat, NineGrainHoneyOat, Italian, ItalianHerbsAndCheese, Flatbread };
```

Can we use a normal list to fetch the values from the database and display it as options?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this out of the box, but you could subclass `FormBuilderBase<T>`, overriding various methods to build the `Form` using whatever datasource you prefer.

**Edit:**

You can find the base class and implementation of `FormBuilder` here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/FormFlow/FormBuilder.cs

Basically, there are a mess of virtual methods that you can override to customize how you want to form to behave, but the main one is `Build`.  In the default implementation, it iterates though the enums to create a list of `Field`, which are basically each step in you form.  Instead of that, you can iterate through whatever data you have pulled from your database and create a new `Field` for each item.  It may look something like this:

```
public override IForm<T> Build(Assembly resourceAssembly = null, string resourceName = null)
{
    var list = GetListOfItemsFromDatabase();
    foreach (var item in _list)
    {
        // FieldFromItem is an IField and will also need to be created
        Field(new FieldFormItem<T>(item));
    }
    Confirm(new PromptAttribute(_form.Configuration.Template(TemplateUsage.Confirmation)));
    }
    return base.Build(resourceAssembly, resourceName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give some more elaborate examples

Answer (score 1):

I know its late but found myself struggling with the same and found that below would be the right solution for this.In your FormFlow class just add the Terms and Descriptions manually.From your example if we are talking about length options then change the type of LengthOptions to string add following code when you build the form.

```
           return new FormBuilder<SandwichForm>()
                .Field(new FieldReflector<SandwichForm>(nameof(LengthOptions))
                        .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
                        {
                            // Call database and get options and iterate over the options
                            field
                            .AddDescription("SixInch","Six Inch")
                            .AddTerms("SixInch", "Six Inch")
                            .AddDescription("FootLong ","Foot Long")
                            .AddTerms("FootLong ", "Foot Long")
                            return true;
                        }))
                .OnCompletion(completionDelegate)
                .Build();
```

Comment: But this does not show the options like an enum would do; right?

Comment: @Jasper its exactly the same thing...only dynamic